# Help writing a query in a very old DBMS

Tags: sql, db2

I've a to work on a very old DB2 database. It has a table which looks like this

```
NODE                  FILE                      SIZE
X                     abc.txt                   23
X                     abc.txt                   23
X                     abc.txt                   28
X                     xyz.txt                   450
Y                     abc.txt                   74
```

I need to write  a query to show output as (X, 478) and (Y, 74). I need to group by each node and file find the sum of maximum sized file alone in case there are duplicate files. I can't use `SELECT * FROM (SELECT...)` construct since the DBMS doesn't support it. Any thoughts?

Comment: What version of DB2 are we talking about?

Comment: if it doesn't support select, how do you retrieve data?

Comment: @Daniel - it looks like it doesn't support sub-selects

Comment: @Daniel - JNK is right. It doesn't support subselects.. there is no PK in the table.. So no chance of using nested subquery too..

Comment: Where does the 478 come from?

Comment: It is an odds-on bet that it supports sub-selects in the WHERE clause; it does not support 'query expressions in the FROM clause' is more plausible, though it would have to be an ancient version of DB2 not to have that support.

Answer (score 1):

Can you do `#Temp` tables?  If not you can probably make a real table and use the logic below.

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP (Node CHAR(1), FILE Varchar(35), SIZE int)

SELECT NODE, FILE, MAX(SIZE)
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY NODE, FILE

SELECT NODE, SUM(SIZE)
FROM #Temp
GROUP BY NODE
```

Basically first step gets all your MAX(SIZE) values and distinct Node/File combinations,  then you just aggregate from that result set for the final result.

**EDIT**

Since you can't do temp tables, just create a normal table, i.e. `TempResults` and drop it at the end.

Comment: Cant do temp tables. that is a prohibited :(

Comment: @Prabhu - then make a real table and drop it.

Comment: Thanks! But creating any table or modifying the DB in any way is prohibited. it is a very sensitive database. Cant write anything into it..

Comment: Is there another DB on the same server you can create a table in?  At my job we have a `Workspace` DB that we use for stuff like this.

Comment: No.. There are no Workspace DBs. The existing DB is READ ONLY.